# Word for "outside of school"

Tags: synonyms

The word probably has the prefix "extra-", but I am not thinking of extracurricular, as that only pertains to that which is outside of the educational curriculum. Any ideas?

Comment: Reality? What does school have to do with it?

Comment: Context would help a great deal, but *extramural* might help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I might actually go with **extra-scholastic** instead. [Extramural](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extramural) could refer to a city, school, or hospital.

Comment: And *extra-scholastic* could refer to neo-Aristotelianism. As with any other word, we gain understanding by context.